# How to add a custom command line switch in Chromium source code

Tags: c++, google-chrome, chromium

I'm attempting to add a custom command line option to the Chromium source code on windows, allowing me to run the browser with a flag like `chrome.exe --my-custom-flag=value`. The goal is to access this value anywhere within the Chromium codebase. However, my attempts so far have been unsuccessful.

I've tried using the following code snippet to read the command line value within the Chromium source:

`std::string value = base::CommandLine::ForCurrentProcess()->GetSwitchValueASCII("my-custom-flag");`

However, this method didn't yield the desired result. I also tried another approach using the `CommandLine::ForCurrentProcess()->HasSwitch()` method to check if the custom flag was present, but it didn't work either.

I would greatly appreciate any advice or guidance on how to properly implement and read a custom command line option in the Chromium source code. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: In which of chrome.exe process types do you call `base::CommandLine::ForCurrentProcess()`?

Comment: I was trying to use it in the navigator.cc file in chromium source code.
https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/renderer/core/frame/navigator.cc I do now have experience with C++ or chromium So I found this approach from chatgpt but it did not work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`third_party/blink/renderer/core/frame/navigator.cc` is a part of Chromium renderer process, you attempt to run your code in a renderer. You command line switch `--my-custom-flag` is not forwarded to a renderer process, it is filtered out in

```
void RenderProcessHostImpl::PropagateBrowserCommandLineToRenderer(
    const base::CommandLine& browser_cmd,
    base::CommandLine* renderer_cmd);
```

Add your switch to the array [`kSwitchNames`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main:content/browser/renderer_host/render_process_host_impl.cc;drc=9248388ff0615ba78b94d9b1e50d4a2e7a1aa014;l=3514) in that member function, and it will be propagated to a renderer process. Note, all switches must be defined without the beginning double dashes `--`.